# Python / Django Users Profile Page URL Turkish Character Problem

Tags: python, django, linux, nginx, plesk

Its working on my localhost. But my server (centos 7-plesk) dosn't wok same code.

Example My user profile link:

**domain.com/user/Maşuka**

This link working on my localhost without any problem.

But this link auto redirect like this and i give 404 error page:

**domain.com/user/Ma%25c5%259fuka/**

where is problem? How can i fix this.

What's the difference between localhost and centos? Why working good only localhost.

Myserver (Nginx - Centos - Plesk)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution by bringing the links to the appropriate structure.

I just use `slugify` in my link like this;

```
<a href="/user/{{ view.author.username|slugify }}/" >@{{ view.author }}</a>
```

then my link convert;

```
domain.com/user/Maşuka
```

to

```
domain.com/user/Masuka
```